# New Moodle requirement

Tags: moodle

I need to include these fields in my Moodle site

There must be:

> ·         Learner Personal Details which will also include disability, municipality, ward
>
> ·         Classroom Training with
>
> ```
>                               I.            Name of the Provider
>
>                             II.            Name of the facilitator
>
>                           III.            Name of the moderator
>
>                          IV.            Start and end date
>
>                            V.            Name or number of the Unit standard
>
>                          VI.            Results that is competent or not yet competent
> ```
>
> ·         Workplace Training with
>
> ```
>                             I.            Name of the employer
>
>                           II.            Address
>
>                         III.            Name of the mentor or supervisor
>
>                         IV.            Start and end date
>
>                           V.            Name of the Unit standard
>
>                         VI.            Final results
> ```
>
> ·         Stipend
>
> ```
>                 I.   Money received per month for the duration of the project
> ```
>
> We must also be able to report the drop outs and the pregnancy, bear in mind that they take maternity leave and come back so we must be able to report that

Answer (score 1):

There are custom fields for the user profile - http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/User_profile_fields

I would suggest using the facetoface module for the classroom and workplace training - you can use custom fields too.

https://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=mod_facetoface

You can record attendance and there are a few reports with it.

It is used extensively in Totara (a distribution of Moodle)

http://help.totaralms.com/Trainer_Led_Courses.htm

You will need to write a local plugin to report on the costs though.

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Local_plugins

Comment: I'll vote for this for its helpfulness, but I would advise that no-effort questions are put on hold rather than answered. We want to discourage help vampires `:-)`